# CKEditor loads in React but shows no UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor

I'm trying to incorporate CkEditor 5 into my complex React + Vite application.

It loads but it does not show its UI.

Here's the [MRE repo](https://github.com/b-rahmani/CkEditorLoadsWithoutUi). Please follow these steps to reproduce:

1. Clone the repo
2. `npm install`
3. `npm run dev`
4. Switch between **Dashboard** and **Post HTML** in the menu
5. See the console
6. You should see that it says CkEditor is ready, but you should see no UI

And the code for CkEditor is in:

```
/src/Components/Form/Fields/HtmlRte.jsx
/src/Components/Form/Fields/RteConfig.jsx
```

Basically, I just copy/pasted the default CKEditor example from the docs:

```
import Field from './Field'
import RteConfig from './RteConfig';
import Control from './Control'
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';
import { useField } from 'Hooks'
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';

const HtmlRte = ({ ...rest }) => {

    const field = useField({
        type: Rte.name,
        ...rest
    })
    const {
        displayValue,
        setDisplayValue,
        setChosenValue,
        label,
        progress,
        isValid,
    } = field;

    return (
        <Field
            {...rest}
            {...field}
        >
            <Control className=" px-0 py-0 border-none">
                <span>CK EDITOR </span>
                <CKEditor
                    editor={ClassicEditor}
                    // config={RteConfig}
                    data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
                    onReady={(editor) => {
                        console.log("Editor is ready to use!", editor);
                    }}
                    onChange={(event, editor) => {
                        const data = editor.getData();
                        console.log({ event, editor, data });
                    }}
                    onBlur={(event, editor) => {
                        console.log("Blur.", editor);
                    }}
                    onFocus={(event, editor) => {
                        console.log("Focus.", editor);
                    }}
                />
            </Control>
        </Field>
    )
}

export default HtmlRte
```

What have I done wrong?